# JPA, Hibernate + EhCache + JoinColumn on empty field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I am using EhCache together with Hibernate, and I am kind of stuck with following thing:

If my entity has fields like:

```
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn VkAuth vka
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn OkAuth oka
```

vka is present but oka is null, vka gets cached but query for oka is being sent every time

I understand that oka is simply not being cached because there is nothing to cache, but what could be the possible workaround for this scenario?